# How use QT WebChannel without webSockets

Tags: html, qt, webview, websocket, webkit

Is possible to use QT QWebChannel without websockets, but using WebKit ICP?
I only found examples using webSockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-index.html) states that:

> It works on all browsers that support Qt WebSockets, [...]. Additionally, a custom transport mechanism can also be implemented using Qt WebSockets to support Qt WebChannel-based communication.

It seems that you cannot use it without `WebSockets`, and it would explain why all the examples you find actually use them.

Anyway, it also states that:

> The transport mechanism is supported out of the box by the two popular web engines, Qt WebKit 2 and Qt WebEngine (experimental).

Despite the fact that it is *experimental*, it looks like an alternative to the `WebSockets`.
Actually, while digging into the linked documentation, I've found [that page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html) where it is said about `WebKit` that it implements internally the required interface and it can be used in place of the `WebSockets`, but no example is provided.

You can find spare information all throughout the linked page, as an example it is said that:

> For HTML clients run inside Qt WebKit, you can load the file via qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js. For external clients you will need to copy the file to your webserver.

Then, it follows a brief description of the steps to be done to achieve the same on those clients, as far as I understand by using no `WebSocket`s in this case.

That said, It seems to me that the solution based on the `WebSockets` is the suggested one, so probably you should reconsider you architecture and use them. Otherwise, be ready to deal with experimental and poor documented features.